# grails: data saved even if I set an error

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I'm using grails 2.4.2 and have in my controller-update method the following code:

```
@Transactional
def update(ErtIncommingInvoice ertIncommingInvoiceInstance) {

    if (ertIncommingInvoiceInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    // Concurrent-Update Test
    if (ertIncommingInvoiceInstance.version != params.version as int) {
        flash.warning = "Another user changed the record! (Concurrent Update Error)"
        ertIncommingInvoiceInstance.errors.rejectValue("ertInfo", "concurrent.update.error")
        respond ertIncommingInvoiceInstance.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }
```

even in the case, the error is detected and the errors-object is set and the method-flow does not execute the

```
    ertIncommingInvoiceInstance.save flush:true, failOnError: true
```

the data is already changed in the database.
The edit-view is shown, but doesn't display the error, only the flash-message.

Where's my error in reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails will call `validate` before any `save` and overwrite whatever you set in the `errors` object. Additionally, Grails will call `save` automatically on your objects after your method finishes. You should either call `discard()` on any objects you've changed but don't wish to persist or create a transaction using a `withTransaction` block and manually roll it back.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gregor Petrin answered, I use now the following code, to check for a concurrent-update and redisplay the changed data from the other user...:

```
@Transactional
def update(ErtIncommingInvoice ertIncommingInvoiceInstance) {

    if (ertIncommingInvoiceInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    // Concurrent-Update Test
    if (ertIncommingInvoiceInstance.version != params.version as int) {
        ertIncommingInvoiceInstance.discard()
        ertIncommingInvoiceInstance = ErtIncommingInvoice.get(params.id)
        ertIncommingInvoiceInstance.errors.reject("concurrent.update.error")
        respond ertIncommingInvoiceInstance.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }
```